# layout_weight of LinearLayout for android doesn't work

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am working with the linear layout. I want to place an image which takes up 20% of the screen. Here are the codes but this doesn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/sky" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/schoolroad" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="8" >
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result is that the left layout takes up 80% of the screen.

What's wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should specify the orientation of your `LinearLayout`

and when you use weight you should set the width (or height) to 0dp corresponding of your orientation.

so if your orientation is vertical you should set the height to zero when using weight.
if it's horizontal than the width should be zero when using weights.

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sky" 

    android:orientation="vertical"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/schoolroad" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8" >
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

For `vertical` orientation, don't forget set `height` to 0dp

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

For `horizontal` orientation, don't forget set `width` to 0dp

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_width="0dp"` instead of `fill_parent` for the child views containing `layout_weight`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/sky" >

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/schoolroad" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="8">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```